# Selected option does not get put into post variable

Tags: php, jquery, post, dropdown, selected

> Edit: Thanks for the help everyone, I've changed the topic since I
>   discovered that the problem was more specific to PHP.

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript and I'm creating a page with a search function that requires the user to enter a region to retrieve information that is region-specific. Within a form, I have included a drop-down menu:

```
<select name="region" id="region">

   <option selected="selected" value="na">NA</option>
   <option value="euw">EUW</option>
   <option value="eune">EUNE</option>
   <option value="tr">TR</option>
   <option value="lan">LAN</option>
   <option value="las">LAS</option>
   <option value="br">BR</option>
   <option value="ru">RU</option>
   <option value="oce">OCE</option>
   <option value="kr">KR</option>
</select>
```

Even if I try to select another region other than the default (NA), when the form is submitted, the value for the $_POST region variable always remains as 'na'.

Also, I have a script on form submit:

```
 <script>
     $(function () {
        $('#myForm').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'redirect.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
                location.reload();

            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>
```

My form:

```
<form id="myForm">
        <li id="search">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Search Word"/>
                <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" tabindex="-1" />

                <select name="region" id="region">

                    <option selected="selected" value="na">NA</option>
                    <option value="euw">EUW</option>
                    <option value="eune">EUNE</option>
                    <option value="tr">TR</option>
                    <option value="lan">LAN</option>
                    <option value="las">LAS</option>
                    <option value="br">BR</option>
                    <option value="ru">RU</option>
                    <option value="oce">OCE</option>
                    <option value="kr">KR</option>

                </select>


            </li>
</form>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['region'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION['region'] = $_POST['region'];

    }
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $_POST['region'] = 'na';   // I think this is where the problem persists
        $_SESSION['region'] = $_POST['region'];
    }
```

?>

It seems like $_POST['region'] is not set.
I've included session_start in both files.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need JS for that at all. Browser will handle that. How do you submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

## OP changed the topic of the question, going to leave my code here just for reference, but I'm fully aware it's not an answer anymore.

I wrote a quick CodePen to test what was going on in your problem, I didn't check with a POST request because I don't have your code, but with jQuery all I had to do was remove the selected atribute from NA:

http://codepen.io/leofontes/pen/ZBGZZZ

```
<select name="region" id="region">

   <option value="na">NA</option>
   <option value="euw">EUW</option>
   <option value="eune">EUNE</option>
   <option value="tr">TR</option>
   <option value="lan">LAN</option>
   <option value="las">LAS</option>
   <option value="br">BR</option>
   <option value="ru">RU</option>
   <option value="oce">OCE</option>
   <option value="kr">KR</option>
</select>

<button id="button">Something</button>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#button").click(function() {
      alert($('#region').val());
   });
});
```

Just click the button to see which option was selected, it works.. Not 100% sure if this is what your problem revolved around but I'm pretty sure it was that simple.

Hope this is what you were looking for, if not let me know so that I can help you out some more ;)

Comment: Hey thanks for your input! I tried removing the selected attribute, but it does nothing :/, I edited my post with my form submit code. I think it has something to do with that, not entirely sure. Within my form tag, I have an input tag of type: text which will take a keyword, an input type: submit, and right after that the select menu. Do you know if arrangement of these elements affects form submit?

Comment: @CSishard personally I dont use the Serialize() function, I usually fetch and send the input myself to prevent situations like yours. Can you add the whole form? Maybe some other error is preventing the input from being collected correctly. Also, try adding the selected="selected" attribute to another option and see if the result changes

Comment: I discovered that the dropdown menu wasn't the problem. Changed the topic entirely. If you could still help me out, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $region = $('#region');
$region.val([]);//now $('#region').val() return undefined
//exacttext version
region.find('option').filter(function (index, elem) { return $(this).html() === textSearchValue; }).prop("selected",true);
//containstext version
region.find('option').filter(function (index, elem) { return $(this).html().indexOf(textSearchValue)>0; }).prop("selected",true);
```

PS: always cache the elements in a $variable

Answer (score 0):

what I usually do is this:

```
$(document).on("change",function(){
  if($("#region").val()!="na"){
    var region=$("#region").val();
    alert(region);
  }
});
```

with this you will be able to check if the value is actually changing, and now you can use that variable wherever you want.
And it will work for everytime the value changes until you submit
Hope this helps!

Comment: if what you want to do is for example:

Comment: Select country: USA, and when they select USA another drop down will be filled with all the states from USA what you can do is inside the on change function, write your ajax, so instead of clicking submit, as soon as they select a country (In you case a region) the next dropdown will automatically fill

Comment: I meant inside of the IF that is inside of the $(document).on("change",function(){})

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found out what I had done wrong...
It was because of a small error in ordering of conditionals in **redirect.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
    $_POST['region'] = 'na';   // Where I thought the problem persisted
    $_SESSION['region'] = $_POST['region'];
}
```

This part of the code will always run even after the $_POST variables are set.
My intention was for it to run when $_POST for region was not set.
As a result, I changed it to the following and it worked.

```
if (!isset($_POST['region'])) {
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $_POST['region'] = 'na';
        $_SESSION['region'] = $_POST['region'];
    }
```

Thanks again everyone!